# Is there any reverse whois service?

Tags: domain, domain-name, whois

Can I get a list of all registered domains for a specific person/company?

Comment: Yes. Try WhoisFreaks reverse whois lookup API tool https://whoisfreaks.com/products/reverse-whois-api.html. It allows you to find the reverse whois record of the domains by using four parameters: Reverse whois with the Email address, Reverse whois with the Owner's name, Reverse whois with the Company name, Reverse whois with the Domain keywords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Reverse Whois Lookup](http://www.domaintools.com/registrant-search/). This is a paid service.

Answer (score 2):

[Reverse Whois](http://www.whoisxmlapi.com/reverse-whois.php) from [Whois API](http://www.whoisxmlapi.com) is the most comprehensive service that allow you to search by registrant name, email, company, and many other fields.

Comment: note although not free, it offers a fairly cheap bulk reverse whois lookup service.

Answer (score 1):

Also found
http://ws.arin.net/whois/

Comment: <<broken link>>

Answer (score -1):

The first search form on [this page](http://tools.web-max.ca/websitesonip.php) seems like it does what you want. I tried "Google" as my query (without quotes) and it returned some results. The results may be incomplete, but it's a jumping off point perhaps. I hope it helps.

Comment: This seems to be a search for domain names.